# errors in hello world xml

Tags: java, android, xml

i am new to android development and was reading a book for it (beginning android 4 development) and while creating hello world i got stuck in few errors, first i solved them but my app was force closing so i copy pasted all thing and got 4 errors :-

> Multiple annotations found at this line:
>       - Attribute is missing the Android namespace prefix
>       - Suspicious namespace: should start with http://
>       - Open quote is expected for attribute "xmlns:android" associated with an element type "LinearLayout".
>       - error: Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)
>
> Unexpected namespace prefix "android" found for tag TextView
>
> Multiple annotations found at this line:
>       - Unexpected namespace prefix "android" found for tag TextView
>       - Attribute is missing the Android namespace prefix
>
> Unexpected namespace prefix "android" found for tag Button

code sample

```
<?xml version ="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android=”http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/ android”
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_orientation="vertical"

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello" />

 <TextView
     android:layout_width=”fill_parent”
     android:layout_height=”wrap_content”
     android:text=”@string/This is my first Android Application!” />

 <Button
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:text="@string/And this is clickable :D" />
```

i dont think there's any mistake in code :/

Comment: Was the above xml same as in the book, i really doubt that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the quotes of every line of code with " and use ctr+sift+f and save the file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello" />

 <TextView
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="@string/This is my first Android Application!" />

 <Button
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="@string/And this is clickable :D" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a copy - paste issue. Replace the quotes in line 2 with " and it should work

Comment: Remove the space between "res/" and "android" in line 2
String names cannot have spaces. For all android:text attributes remove "@string/"

Answer (score 0):

Replace ” with "" in your xml to make it a valid xml

Answer (score 0):

```
apk/res/ android
```

delete the space here, using

```
apk/res/android
```

Answer (score 0):

@string resources should be declare in strings.xml, try this ! And read more

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

     <TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="hello" />

     <TextView
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="This is my first Android Application!" />

     <Button
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="And this is clickable :D" />

    </LinearLayout>
```