# Error:(9) Error: Suspicious namespace and prefix combination [NamespaceTypo] when building signed apk release

Tags: android, xml

I've checked online for a solution tried solutions from this page: [Error: Suspicious namespace and prefix combination [NamespaceTypo] when I try create Signed APK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34159322/error-suspicious-namespace-and-prefix-combination-namespacetypo-when-i-try-cr) and also [errors in hello world xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17280767/errors-in-hello-world-xml) but there's no solution. The funny thing is when I try to build a debug of the app or a release for tv and wear everything works well. Error:

```
  (9) Error: Suspicious namespace and prefix combination [NamespaceTypo]
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  
  Explanation for issues of type "NamespaceTypo":
  Accidental misspellings in namespace declarations can lead to some very
 obscure error messages. This check looks for potential misspellings to  help track these down.
  1 errors, 0 warnings
```

Layout file part of the code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:materialdesign="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">
```

A solution to this is very helpful

Answer (score 5):

Instead of what you have on line 3:

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

Use:

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

Answer (score 2):

Please change your namespace

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

to

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the problem...I had been working on the project using Android Studio version 1.0 and got the problem when I updated to version 1.5.1 So all I did is just getting back to the old version and things were okay, I have no idea why this is the case...

Answer (score 0):

You can reproduce those errors  by using the tool Analyse->Inspect code in android studio.
in the xml make sure that

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

and

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools".
```

If you can write like  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools" ,you will get an error.